# Using two for loops to fill one empty matrix by rows

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I'm trying to do a forecast analysis with some error measures. My question relates more to a technical Problem.
Here is a short example:
Im studying error measures regarding to the forecast length (h) and the k-step-forecast. I want to compare forecast lengths of 12, 18 and 24 months.

```
h<-c(12,18,24)
```

And for that lengths I'm comparing the 1-12 step ahead forecasts.

```
k <- c(1:12)
```

I've written two functions:
The first one (foo) is computing the hole code and the second one (forecast_analysis) is doing my forecast Analysis.

```
 foo <- function(series, k, h){

 Outfinal <- matrix(nrow = length(h)*length(k), ncol = 5) 

 for(i in 1:length(h)){
  for(j in 1:length(k)){
    Outfinal[j,] <- forecast_analysis(series,k[j],h[i]) 
  }
 }
return(Outfinal)
}
```

my Problem is, that I couldnt find a way to fill the Matrix by rows like this:

```
h    k         measure 1 measure 2 measure3 measure 4 measure 5
12   1
12   2
12   3
.    .
.    .
.    .
24   10
24   11
24   12
```

So, first I want to fill the Matrix for a fixed value of h for all values of k. And then repeating this for all values of h. I hope ure understanding my Problem.

I know that apply functions would be more efficient here. But I'm not yet able to do so.

Comment: The double loop confuses me. You are assigning to the j'th row for each i x j combination. Do you want to assign a value for each combination of `h` and `k`?

Comment: Thats the point, where im stucking. Each combination of i and j should be filled in that matrix by rows. With the approach  Outfinal[j,] the Loops is filling correctly in the first 12 lines of error measures for h=12 and then it's overwriting them for h=18, obviously

Comment: See my update on how to handle when the analysis function returns more than a single value.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a table of all h x k combinations plus a result using `expand.grid`.

This code should get you started

```
dummy_forecast <- function(h, k) 42
h<-c(12,18,24)
k <- 1:12 # no need for the c function here

combinations <- expand.grid(h = h, k = k, forecast = NA)
for (row in seq_along(combinations$h)) {
    combinations[row, "forecast"] <- 
       with(combinations[row,], dummy_forecast(h, k))
}
```

If you return more than one value from your function, you need to assign to more than one column in `combinations[row,...]`, but otherwise it should work.

**Update**

To handle a function that returns more than one value, do something like this:

```
dummy_forecast <- function(h, k) rep(42, 5)

result <- matrix(nrow = length(h) * length(k), ncol = 7)
combinations <- expand.grid(h = h, k = k)
for (row in seq_along(combinations$h)) {
    result[row,] <- with(combinations[row,], c(h, k, dummy_forecast(h, k)))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I'll try that. But where I should implement my function (forecast_Analysis), that computes my Analysis. Would there be still a way to do it in a way like in my example ?

Comment: You didn't show in your example where you defined `forecast_Analysis`, so I don't know. But do it where I implemented `dummy_forecast` and you will be fine.

Comment: It's just a selfwritten function, that computes me 5 error measures as vector (1x5). The function requires a time series, the forecast lentgh h and the k-step ahead forecast k. So, I want for each combination the 5 measures in a matrix